# Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, and Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

pls help me i wasted 1 week fixing this issue but nothing works in my case its a version issue How to fix these errors i am using expo react native and my react native version 0.70.5 and my expo version 46 you can check that what i have tried but nothings works for me this error came after i fix
a error which is `ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types`

i have done nothing works

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['babel-preset-expo'],
  ],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

and `npm  start --reset-cache`

ERROR:

```
 ERROR  Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\index.ts", which threw an exception: Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, make sure you followed installation steps here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-n initialize react-native-reanimaative-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/                                                                               ls/installation/
1) Make sure reanimated's babel plugin is installed in your babel.config.js (you should have 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' listed there - also see the aboveisted there - also see the above link for details)
2) Make sure you reset build cache after updating the config, run: yarn start --reset-cache
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered istered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLogveAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerform, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.    
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an endle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered istered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLogveAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerform, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.    
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an endle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

Comment: Is any library using react-native-reanimated, and which version of RN is being used

Comment: @Azzy this project is not made by me its a open source project their at GitHub pls check it https://github.com/shahshubh/SocialApp-React-Native i am using react native "0.70.5

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it worked after running following command

`expo start -c`